# Does Roku Device is Required for Roku Development / Testing..(Simple Hello World App)

Tags: roku

I'm new to Roku development, and facing very basic issues. I am unable to understand, how will i test my app.

I read that we can't test Roku app on simulator, and only on real device. So:
Do i need to buy Roku device?
What's the best testing strategy?

Please help. Thanks

Comment: This information is available on the Roku website. See https://developer.roku.com/develop/getting-started/setup-guide

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have a Roku device in order to develop and test Roku applications.  You can currently purchase a brand new Roku express for about $30 US.  If you are building an application that will be certified by Roku for availability in their public channel store, you may very well need to obtain several models of Roku for testing and development, since they require certain performance on all supported models, and the older models are notoriously challenging. See: https://developer.roku.com/develop/channel-store/certification

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need Roku device. Also you need smart TV for connecting to device. with same connectivity with Internet. I hope my answer will helpful